# "Subcribe" to the weekly newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, newsletter

Some sites have a right sidebar advertisement for the newsletter which triggers a popup for anonymous users (and maybe some others) to enter an email address where they'd like the email to be sent. The submit button on this popup form erroneously says "Subcribe" without the "s" in it:

> [image: Subcribe button]

Comment: You see what's happening when you report bugs? Oded fixes them and gains rep! You'll never surpass him by rep! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo fixed, with you in the next build.